# No Free lunches and price uniqueness relation problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

In the article *Martingales and arbitrage in multiperiod securities markets* from J Michael Harrison and David M. Kreps, they begin considering a market with time interval $[0, T]$ with only two periods $0$ and $T$. In this market they consider $(Z_{t})$ as a $k+1$ dimensional process adapted with respect to $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_{t \in \lbrace 0, T\rbrace}, P)$ where $Z^{(k)}_{t}$ represents the value of the $k$-th asset at time $t$, and $Z_{t}^{(0)}=1$  for all $t$ and $w \in \Omega$. They assume that $\mathcal{F}_{0} = \lbrace \emptyset, \Omega \rbrace $. They define a *self-financing simple strategy* as a process $(\theta_{t})$ such that it satisfies the following

1. $(\theta_{t})$ is a process $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ adapted
2. $\theta_{t}\cdot Z_{t} \in  L^{2}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ for all $t$
3. $\theta_{t}$ is constant over the interval $[0,T)$ (this is the case for only two periods. This can emmediately be generalized to the scenario of more than two periods )
4. $\theta_{t_{n-1}}\cdot Z_{t_{n}} = \theta_{t_{n}}\cdot Z_{t_{n}} $ where $t_{n} = 0$ for $n=0$; and $t_{n} = T$ for $n=1$. (*self-financing property*)

> They say that a *self-financing* strategy $\theta$, is a *free lunch* if $\theta_{0} \cdot Z_{0} \leq 0$ and $\theta_{T} \cdot Z_{T} \in (L^{2}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P))^{+}$

The authors say that in order to price a claim $x \in L^{2}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ in only one way,  we  must ensure that if there exist two strategies $(\theta_{t})$ and $(\theta^{*}_{t})$  such that $\theta_{T}\cdot S_{T} = x = \theta^{*}_{T} \cdot S_{T} $, then $\theta_{0}\cdot S_{0} = \theta^{*}_{0} \cdot S_{0} $.

The author claimed this proposition:

> If the there is not *free lunches*, then  for all *self-financing* strategies $(\theta_{t})$ and $(\theta^{*}_{t})$  such that $\theta_{T}\cdot S_{T} = x = \theta^{*}_{T} \cdot S_{T} $, we get $\theta_{0}\cdot S_{0} = \theta^{*}_{0} \cdot S_{0} $.

**Quesiton** I wonder if there is something else that is not mentioned in this article, because this proposition is not true.

Consider this counter example

$\theta_{t} =(a_{t}, b_{t}, c_{t})_{t \in  \lbrace 0, T \rbrace}, \ \ \ \ \theta^{*}_{t} =(a^{*}_{t}, b^{*}_{t}, c^{*}_{t})_{t \in  \lbrace 0, T \rbrace}, \ \ \ \ Z_{t} =(1, Z^{(1)}_{t}, Z^{(2)}_{t})_{t \in  \lbrace 0, T \rbrace}$

with $Z^{(1)}_{t}, Z^{(2)}_{t} > 0$ for all $t$

Now consider the following set of equations

1. $a_{T} + b_{T}Z^{(1)}_{T} + c_{T}Z^{(2)}_{T} = \gamma $ with $\gamma >0$
2. $a^{*}_{T} + b^{*}_{T}Z^{(1)}_{T} + c^{*}_{T}Z^{(2)}_{T} = \gamma $
3. $a_{0} + b_{0}Z^{(1)}_{T} + c_{0}Z^{(2)}_{T} = \gamma $
4. $a^{*}_{0} + b^{*}_{0}Z^{(1)}_{T} + c^{*}_{0}Z^{(2)}_{T} = \gamma $
5. $a_{0} + b_{0}Z^{(1)}_{0} + c_{0}Z^{(2)}_{0} = \alpha $
6. $a^{*}_{0} + b^{*}_{0}Z^{(1)}_{0} + c^{*}_{0}Z^{(2)}_{0} = \alpha^{*} $

with $\alpha, \alpha^{*} > 0$ and $\alpha \neq \alpha^{*} $

If $\begin{vmatrix} Z^{(1)}_{T} & Z^{(2)}_{T} \\ Z^{(1)}_{0} & Z^{(2)}_{0} \end{vmatrix} \neq 0 $ we get that

$\left[ \begin{matrix} Z^{(1)}_{T} & Z^{(2)}_{T} \\ Z^{(1)}_{0} & Z^{(2)}_{0}  \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} b_{0}^{*} \\ c_{0}^{*}   \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} \gamma - a_{0}^{*} \\ \alpha^{*} - a_{0}^{*} \end{matrix} \right]  (\text{equation 4 and equation 6})$

and

$\left[ \begin{matrix} Z^{(1)}_{T} & Z^{(2)}_{T} \\ Z^{(1)}_{0} & Z^{(2)}_{0}  \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} b_{0} \\ c_{0}   \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} \gamma - a_{0} \\ \alpha - a_{0} \end{matrix} \right]  (\text{equation 3 and equation 5})$

have a solution for $Z_{t} =(1, Z^{(1)}_{t}, Z^{(2)}_{t})_{t \in  \lbrace 0, T \rbrace}$; $\gamma > 0$, and $\alpha, \alpha^{*} > 0$ and $\alpha \neq \alpha^{*} $.

Notice that

1. Equations 1) and 2) are equivalent to say that $\theta_{T} \cdot Z_{T} = \gamma = \theta^{*}_{T} \cdot Z^{*}_{T}$
2. Equations 3) and 4) are equivalent to say that  $\theta_{T} \cdot Z_{T} = \theta_{0} \cdot Z_{T}$ and $\theta^{*}_{T} \cdot Z_{T} = \theta^{*}_{0} \cdot Z_{T}$
3. Equations 5) and 6) are equiavalent to say that $\theta_{0} \cdot Z_{0} = \alpha  > 0 $ and   $\theta^{*}_{0} \cdot Z_{0} = \alpha  > 0 $, but $ \theta_{0} \cdot Z_{0} \neq \theta^{*}_{0} \cdot Z_{0}$ . In other word strategies that are not *free lunch* and compute different prices.

I choosed this example because this is pretty easy to work with random variables equal to constants. This also can be done with random variable differnt from constants using the same method but multiplying each one of the terms by their respective probability. The inequalities hold using convex combinations and changing the probabilities (the convex coefficients) in order to get the inequalities.

The proposition holds if we assume that $(Z_t)$ is supermartingale, but the authors do not say anything else about the $Z$ in the article.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's assume $a^* > a$. So what about $\theta^X = \theta - \theta^* + \epsilon \theta^*$ (where $\epsilon$ is a tiny number). Won't you have $\theta^X_0 \cdot Z_0 \leq 0$ and $\theta^X_T \cdot Z_T \succ 0$?

Comment: It may be the case, but the important thing is that with this example, I am showing that given $(Z_{t})$ there exists $\gamma, \alpha, \alpha^{*}$  and two self-financing  portfolio strategies $\theta$ and $\theta^{*}$ that are not free lunches and that $\theta_{T} \cdot Z_{T} = \theta^{*}_{T} \cdot Z_{T} $ but  $\theta_{0} \cdot Z_{0} \neq \theta^{*}_{0} \cdot Z_{0} $ and this implies that the proposition does not hold. Imagine that you have a claim $v$ and that $v = \theta_{T} \cdot Z_{T} = \theta^{*}_{T} \cdot Z_{T}$ then you do not have a unique implicit price.

Comment: Showing $\theta$ and $\theta^*$ are not free lunches is not sufficient. You have to show that no free lunch can possibly exist.

Comment: I do not understand your point. You can choose numbers $Z_{t} =(1, Z^{(1)}_{t}, Z^{(2)}_{t})_{t \in  \lbrace 0, T \rbrace}$; $\gamma > 0$, and $\alpha, \alpha^{*} > 0$ and $\alpha \neq \alpha^{*} $ such that the determinant mentioned above is different from zero. Now with this and solving  the equations mentioned before you can constuct the two self-financing portfolio strategies that are not free lunch, and  have the same value at $t=T$ but different value at time $t=0$. This is an example of two strategies not free lunch but with different price.

Comment: The proposition says no free lunch implies unique price at time $t=0$.

Comment: I'll assume $a^* > a$. Let $\epsilon =1 - \frac{a}{a^*} > 0$. Define $\theta^X = \theta - (1 - \epsilon) \theta^*$. Hence $\theta^X_0 \cdot Z_0 = a - ( 1 - \epsilon)a^* = 0$.  We also have $\theta^X_T \cdot Z_T = \gamma - (1 - \epsilon) \gamma = \epsilon \gamma > 0$. Therefore $\theta^X$ is a free lunch: it costss 0 at time 0 but has a positive payoff of $\epsilon \gamma$ at time $T$. Since $\theta^X$ is a free lunch, the no free lunch condition is violated.

Comment: I understood your point. It can be proved directly. Suppose not. Without loss of generality, take \theta_0\cdot S_0 < \theta*_0\cdot S_0.
Consider the trading strategy \phi= \theta-\theta*.

We have \phi_0\cdot S_0 <0 and \phi_T\cdot S_T= x-x=0.

So, \phi is a free lunch. QED